# Lambda multiple conditions to validate list in list of object?

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0

I have a list composed of the following items

```
List<person> lst = new List<person>()
lst.Add(new person(){ name="abc", age="24" });
lst.Add(new person(){ name="xyz", age="25" });
lst.Add(new person(){ name="zxc", age="28" });
lst.Add(new person(){ name="wer", age="38" });

List<string> strlst = new List<string>();
strlst.Add("abc");
strlst.Add("zxc");
```

right now i am validating the list

```
lst.Exists(a => strlst.Contains(a.name))
```

How can I validate the entire list if it contains 'abc`and`xyz`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe your original intent is to validate against your `lst` variable, not `strlst`. If it's for `strlist`, then I believe @LosManos's answer is a very good approach. If you are trying to validate `List<person> lst` with the values in `strlst` then you should do the following:

```
var allNames = lst.Select(l => l.name);
var containsAll = strlist.All(s => allNames.Contains(s));
```

This way would also ensure that you could do it correctly even if you have more than two things you need to compare on.

Comment: Note this is a rather inefficient operation as you are performing a linear search of all of the people for each string that you are searching for, so it won't scale well for large data sets.  For small data sets it will be fine.

Comment: Can you suggest any other method to that?

Comment: @Pravin Sure, just see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you find the `Intersect` of the two names you get the names common to both lists.  If that intersection is the same size as your string list then it means all of them are in the intersection, which means they're all in the other list.

```
return list.Select(person => person.name)
       .Intersect(strlst).Count() == strlst.Count();
```